# Downgrading GTK+3 application

Tags: gtk, gtk3

We have a gtk 3 application but planning to integrate webkit engine with it.But the chrome does not support gtk+3 application.So how to downgrading out application to gtk+2

Comment: please, be more specific. do you have the source code? which language is your application?

Comment: Our Application is in C++.I wanted to know to if there is way to downgrade application with GTK+3 to GTK+2 using the GTK-2 library.Can i compile straight ahead with GTK2 library or should i be worried with dependent libraries of GTK

Comment: Vinay, please try to compile with GTK2 first and then ask help with any problems you encounter.

Comment: i did get such errors undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_style_context and to similar api's after compiling with gtk2 library

Comment: @vinay Chrome is _not_ WebKit, especially when you speak of toolkit support. Integrating a WebKit view into a GTK+ 3 app should be fairly easy: just use libwebkitgtk-3.0. I would suggest trying that before downgrading your app.

Answer (score 1):

This may be simple to hard, depending on the number of symbols that are new in GTK 3 you're using. You'll need to see how it was done before, back in GTK 2. That looks a bit awkward. Doesn't [WebkitGTK](https://wiki.gnome.org/WebKitGtk) support GTK 3 ?

Comment: Yes: WebKitGTK has separate libraries for both GTK+ 2 and 3.